# Get a specific value in array Mongodb and Symfony 2

Tags: json, mongodb, symfony

I have a field ‘preferences’ in my Document, and datas like this:

```
{"visibility":"true","create":"2013-06-15 15:09:51","update":1371301791}
{"visibility":"false","create":"2013-06-15 15:09:51","update":1371301791}
```

I want to get the rows with visibility=’true’.
I have tried something like this but no result:

```
$datas = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')
                ->getRepository('ApplicationMtbeBundle:myDoc')
                 ->createQueryBuilder()
                 ->field("preferences.visibility")->equals("true")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Sure the visibility values are strings and not booleans?

Comment: You've used `preference` instead of `preferences` in your query...Is that correct?